# Stored procedure select based on year and month

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm having trouble with my query, I'm trying to display data depending on the year and the month of an input. I'm hallway there it shows the month entered but it brings up data from all the years with that particular month.

```
         PROCEDURE `date_passed`(in date date)
        BEGIN
        SELECT table1.name, table1.licence, table2.date
        FROM table1
    inner join table2
    on
    table2.table1_idtable1 = table1.idtable1
    where  MONTH (date)= MONTH(date)
    and 
    result='passed'
```

Comment: That's because your code is not doing anything about the year.

Comment: I did attempt something along prdp's first answer and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `YEAR` function to filter year part from dates

```
SELECT table1.NAME,
       table1.licence,
       table2.date
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN table2
               ON table2.table1_idtable1 = table1.idtable1
WHERE  Month (date) = Month(input_date)
       AND Year(date) = Year(input_date)
       AND result = 'passed'
```

A better approach with some date functions. It will use index on date column if any.

```
SELECT table1.NAME,
       table1.licence,
       table2.date
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN table2
               ON table2.table1_idtable1 = table1.idtable1
WHERE  date >= cast(Date_format(input_date, '%Y-%m-01') as date)
       AND date < DATE_ADD(cast(Last_day(input_date) as date),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       AND result = 'passed'
```

Comment: @DanBracuk Even am not a Mysql user I just had the idea and googled it to get the relevant functions. I think I addressed both the issues

Comment: Unfortunately both of these didn't work :(. I did try something along your first answer before coming here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChristopherInfinity - What do you mean by didnt work? Are you getting any error. If you are not getting expected results then add sample data and expected result

Comment: @Prdp Well the first option does the same as my original code displays data that meet the month and year isn't considered, the second one just does the same